# Continuously play the gif on image using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to place multiple gif on image and save as gif using FFmpeg. I had achieved placing of multiple gif but all gif doesnot play continuously i.e Second gif repeat only once first gif finish and started again ..the second gif stop and start again only when first gif finishes.

```
command_try[0]="-i";
    command_try[1]=input;
    command_try[2]="-i";
    command_try[3]=gifthumbnail;
    command_try[4]="-i";
    command_try[5]=gifthumbnail;
    command_try[6]="-i";
    command_try[7]=thumbnail;
    command_try[8]="-i";
    command_try[9]=thumbnail2;
    command_try[10]="-filter_complex";
    command_try[11]="[0:v]scale=0:0[base];[1:v]scale=300:-1[img1];[2:v]scale=720:-1290[img2];[3:v]scale=80:-1[img3];[4:v]scale=50:-1[img4];[img1]rotate=45:c=black@0:ow=rotw(45):oh=roth(45)[r1];[img2]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[r2];" +
            "[img3]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[r3];[img4]rotate=0:c=black@0:ow=rotw(0):oh=roth(0)[r4];[base][r1]overlay=100:70[tmp1];"+
            "[tmp1][r2]overlay=55:55[tmp2];[tmp2][r3]overlay=65:65[tmp3];[tmp3][r4]overlay=30:30";

    command_try[12]="-preset";
    command_try[13]="veryfast";
    command_try[14]="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/imggif.gif";
```

As I am recently started working on FFmpeg need help to play gif continuously independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-stream_loop -1` input option and add the `shortest=1` option to any overlay with an infinitely looping GIF as an input.

Simplified example:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i 1.gif -filter_complex "overlay=shortest=1:format=auto" output.mp4
```

To avoid the yellow lines add the [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen) and [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i 1.gif -filter_complex "overlay=shortest=1:format=auto,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

You are using FFmpeg 3.0.1 which is really old so you will have to change `auto` to `rgb`.

Comment: I am using stream_loop attribute when I am overlaying the gif on video and its working perfectly fine.But I am now trying to overlay multiple gif on image and need to loop the gif continuously independent of other.

Comment: @ShwetaPatil Add a `-stream_loop` before each GIF input.

Comment: Ok I will try -stream_loop for image as well.But won't it increases the processing time to save the gif

Comment: @ShwetaPatil It depends on the length of `video.mp4`.

Comment: ok. So I will limit the video length so that large video will not be selected and processing will not be affected much.

Comment: The gif saved on image sometimes shows yellow lines at top ..can you tell me what can be the issue

Comment: @ShwetaPatil Show your command and the complete log. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TDFpw2BY .The link contains the command and the log.           Image link: https://pasteboard.co/IVnkwfW.jpg                                                             Result gif: https://pasteboard.co/IVnkNgc.gif.                                                           Check and let me know the issue.

Comment: @ShwetaPatil Thanks. Can you also provide a link `1580388461.gif`?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IVvkCVZ.gif contains the gif which has be overlayed. Did you found any solution for it?

Comment: @ShwetaPatil Answer updated. The problem can be duplicated with `ffmpeg -i white.png -i 1580388461.gif -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=format=rgb" output.gif`. It would have saved us both much time (several days) if you would have simplified the command to a minimal example that still exhibits the issue and provided all required inputs.